# Utilizando obspy.taup con variables de una fila de un .txt

Tags: python-3.x

Estoy intentando conformar un código para utilizar con un módulo del paquete obspy. El código viene a decir que de un .txt, que en mi caso tiene una fila con cinco valores separados por comas (ejemplo: 1,2,3,4,5) los utilice como variables en la instrucción del módulo de obspy. Pongo el código y creo que lo entenderéis mejor.

```
from obspy.taup import TauPyModel
model = TauPyModel(model="iasp91")

archivo=open('Dato.txt', 'r')
for linea in archivo.readlines():
    columna = str(linea).split(',')
    print(columna[0])
    print(columna[1])
    print(columna[2])
    print(columna[3])
    print(columna[4])
archivo.close()

a=columna[0]
b=columna[1]
c=columna[2]
d=columna[3]
e=columna[4]

arrivals=model.get_pierce_points_geo(a, b, c, d, e, phase_list=('SKS',), resample=False)

arrival = arrivals[0]

print(arrival.pierce)
```

Si las variables las defino como valores numéricos (ejemplo: a=408; b=47.6981; c=146.9212; etc ….), el código funciona y me devuelve lo que quiero (como por ejemplo aquí):

```
408
47.6981
146.9212
36.882277
-3.068689
C:\Users\peopl\Desktop\BO\env\lib\site-packages\obspy\taup\tau_branch.py:496: UserWarning: Resizing a TauP array inplace failed due to the existence of other references to the array, creating a new array. See Obspy #2280.
  warnings.warn(msg)
[ ( 323.37738085,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   408.        ,  47.6981    ,  146.9212    )
 ( 323.37738085,   4.25942791e-01,   9.18383444e-05,   410.        ,  47.70292225,  146.9180712 )
 ( 323.37738085,   4.95211705e+01,   1.33680904e-02,   660.        ,  48.39912219,  146.45957792)
 ( 323.37738085,   4.30994629e+02,   3.09568047e-01,  2889.        ,  63.17117462,  131.25054174)
 ( 323.37738085,   6.19102877e+02,   7.88455257e-01,  3482.54497821,  73.50766588,   55.65029149)
 ( 323.37738085,   8.07211124e+02,   1.26734247e+00,  2889.        ,  54.05973754,    7.50927585)
 ( 323.37738085,   1.18868458e+03,   1.56354242e+00,   660.        ,  38.47340944,   -2.34102958)
 ( 323.37738085,   1.23777981e+03,   1.57681868e+00,   410.        ,  37.75869395,   -2.67200616)
 ( 323.37738085,   1.23820575e+03,   1.57691051e+00,   408.        ,  37.75374671,   -2.67427329)
 ( 323.37738085,   1.28179336e+03,   1.58536568e+00,   210.        ,  37.29809076,   -2.88171143)
 ( 323.37738085,   1.32180477e+03,   1.59207012e+00,    35.        ,  36.93652754,   -3.04441779)
 ( 323.37738085,   1.32587993e+03,   1.59253065e+00,    20.        ,  36.91168346,   -3.05553737)
 ( 323.37738085,   1.33192110e+03,   1.59307573e+00,     0.        ,  36.882277  ,   -3.068689  )]
```

Sin embargo, al utilizar el código definiendo las variables del .txt me devuelve lo siguiente:

```
408
47.6981
146.9212
36.882277
-3.068689
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pierce.py", line 20, in <module>
    arrivals=model.get_pierce_points_geo(a, b, c, d, e, phase_list=('SKS',), resample=False)
  File "C:\Users\peopl\Desktop\BO\env\lib\site-packages\obspy\taup\tau.py", line 784, in get_pierce_points_geo
    distance_in_deg = calc_dist(source_latitude_in_deg,
  File "C:\Users\peopl\Desktop\BO\env\lib\site-packages\obspy\taup\taup_geo.py", line 53, in calc_dist
    return calc_dist_azi(source_latitude_in_deg, source_longitude_in_deg,
  File "C:\Users\peopl\Desktop\BO\env\lib\site-packages\obspy\taup\taup_geo.py", line 86, in calc_dist_azi
    g = ellipsoid.Inverse(source_latitude_in_deg,
  File "C:\Users\peopl\Desktop\BO\env\lib\site-packages\geographiclib\geodesic.py", line 1035, in Inverse
    a12, s12, salp1,calp1, salp2,calp2, m12, M12, M21, S12 = self._GenInverse(
  File "C:\Users\peopl\Desktop\BO\env\lib\site-packages\geographiclib\geodesic.py", line 712, in _GenInverse
    lon12, lon12s = Math.AngDiff(lon1, lon2)
  File "C:\Users\peopl\Desktop\BO\env\lib\site-packages\geographiclib\geomath.py", line 156, in AngDiff
    d, t = Math.sum(Math.AngNormalize(-x), Math.AngNormalize(y))
TypeError: bad operand type for unary -: 'str'
```

Los valores numéricos son los que tengo en mi .txt, pero parece que da un problema al utilizarlo en la instrucción que necesito. Agradecería que me echaseis una mano en esto. Soy novato (información...jejeje).

Un saludo a la comunidad y gracias.

Gracias a Roberto conseguí que el código funcione. Pongo aquí el script con el que consigo mi objetivo:

```
from obspy.taup import TauPyModel
model = TauPyModel(model="iasp91")

arrivals = []
with open('Dato.txt', 'rt') as archivo:
    for linea in archivo:
        columna = str(linea).strip().split(',')
        a = float(columna[0])
        b = float(columna[1])
        c = float(columna[2])
        d = float(columna[3])
        e = float(columna[4])
        arrival = model.get_pierce_points_geo(a, b, c, d, e, phase_list=('SKS',), resample=False)
        arrivals.append(arrival)

print('Las llegadas procesadas son:', len(arrivals))
for arrival in arrivals:
    arrivals=arrival[0]
    print(arrivals.pierce)
```

Parece ser que la instrucción arrivals=arrival[0] es necesaria porque al no incluirla me decía que había un error en print(arrival.pierce). Ahora está solucionado. Muchas gracias a todos. Sigo trabajando para intentar entrar en este mundo...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes convertir las variables en numéricas, cuando se leen del fichero se leen como cadenas (`str`)

```
a = float(columna[0])
b = float(columna[1])
c = float(columna[2])
d = float(columna[3])
e = float(columna[4])
```

Por otro lado, tal y como tienes el código sólo usas la última linea del fichero, ya que utilizas los valores después del bucle que lee el fichero, es un tanto extraño.

Yo estructuraría el código de la siguiente manera:

```
from obspy.taup import TauPyModel
model = TauPyModel(model="iasp91")

arrivals = []
with open('Dato.txt', 'rt') as archivo:
    for linea in archivo:
        columna = str(linea).strip().split(',')
        a = float(columna[0])
        b = float(columna[1])
        c = float(columna[2])
        d = float(columna[3])
        e = float(columna[4])
        arrival = model.get_pierce_points_geo(a, b, c, d, e, phase_list=('SKS',), resample=False)
        arrivals.append(arrival)

print('Las llegadas procesadas son:', len(arrivals))
for arrival in arrivals:
    print(arrival[0].pierce)
```

De esta forma procesas todas las líneas del fichero y la gestión de "cierre" (close) del fichero es automática y más segura, el uso de la sentencia [`with`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) está recomendado para el trabajo con ficheros.

Comment: Gracias. Esto ha solucionado el problema. De momento solo tenía una fila en el fichero .txt. ¿Cómo debería de modificar el código para un fichero .txt con varias filas y que lo haga para cada una de ellas? Muchas gracias.

Comment: Luego si encuentro un rato actualziado la respuesta con ese detalle, a modo de resumen se debe añadir el cálculo dentro del bucle for, y convertir `arrivals` en un list que almacene tantos resultados como filas tenga el fichero

Comment: Perfecto. Mientras tanto intento hacerlo con el resumen que me has dado. Aunque dudo que consiga aclararlo sin un empujoncito más. Gracias.

Comment: He actualizado la respuesta con el código completo, según como yo lo enfocaría

Comment: Gracias. Lo utilicé tal cual me lo aconsejaste y no me funcionó. Yo hice una pequeña modificación y conseguí que al fin funcione. Lo intento poner como código en la parte final de mi pregunta. Muchas gracias de nuevo.

Comment: Ok, tienes razón, como no pude ejecutarlo al no tener las dependencias me faltaba un detalle, he actualizado la respuesta de todas formas.